# New design issues

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

There's a few places where we have blue & black text on a blue background:

1. **Badge lookup**:
   [image: badge lookup display]
   <sub>Previous version: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqJea.png</sub>
   *Update*: the issue now is the over-large bottom border when the "awarded to" section is short.
2. **Timeline screen**:
   [image: timeline display]
3. **Revisions screen**:
   [image: revisions screen]
   <sub>Previous version: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTeqC.png</sub>
   *Update*: now looking much better; only current issue (imo) is the black "Return to Question" header on the dark blue background.

There may be others, but these are the ones I've run across.

I don't *think* that any of them are due to my custom CSS or GreaseMonkey scripts, but if they are, feel free to publicly point at me and laugh.

---

#### Edits:

***January 30, 2011***: updated 1 & 3 with new screenshots and updated descriptions.

Comment: @Dori: I've also seen this on the mod tools screen, you may want to add it to your question.

Comment: Not your styles, a problem for me too.

Comment: Dori I'm fixing the mod/badge pages this weekend.

Comment: The hardest part about the Apple design conversion was the different in background colors. The SO HTMLs aren't really set up for this. For the Apple site I had to request a few HTML changes to the dev team. The badge page was fine soon after the launch, but we found out the HTML change caused some network wide bugs, so we had to revert it. Instead of changing the html, we'll add more css hooks instead. Same goes for the mod pages. btw I hope you had fun at Macworld Expo!

Comment: Woo published author, nice! The challenging part isn't the actual CSS styling, it's more about applying CSS around SO's HTMLs. We're adding more hooks so the same CSS classes can be styled differently per page, per section etc. This isn't typically a problem since most SE sites have one solid color for the site bg, or content section.

Comment: @Dori, I didn't mean it that way either ! Any help is welcome of course! Sibling selector is a great suggestion. I think it'd help me a great deal without adding much html hooks.

Comment: In fact your sibling selector suggestion just helped me to fix the badge page. thanks! it will be in the next build.

Comment: @Dori, I've fixed the issues in the updated screenshots. Please verify.

Answer (score 3):

Dori, I have fixed the badge page and the mod sections. The changes should be in the next deployment. Thanks.