# Why are some posts "highlighted"?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the significance of the blue background on some questions?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/684/what-is-the-significance-of-the-blue-background-on-some-questions)

Why are some posts "highlighted" blue on the main page?
[image]